# string size stays zero

Tags: c++

I made this function

the input string is something like this "the little fox was white"
I'm calling this function myword=my_copy_from(input,11,3)
I was hopping I would get the word "fox" back but when I used the debugger I saw that the size of back is staying 0 bytes.

Why is that???
thanks

```
    // start of my_copy_from //
     string my_copy_from(string in,short start,short len)
     {
    string back ;
    short i;

    for (i=0 ; i<len; i++)
    {
      back[i]=' ';
      back[i]=in[start+i];


    }

    return back;
}
   // end of my_copy_from //
```

Comment: Why not to use `int` instead of `short`?

Comment: `back[i] = ' ';`. Isn't it a useless statement?

Answer (score 4):

Indexing a string beyond its end results in undefined behavior. You're lucky that the program didn't crash.

You must resize the string in advance.

```
back.resize(len);
```

However, it might be easier to use the [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) member function.

```
return in.substr(start, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string back;
```

creates a string without any memory allocated. So your `for` loop is undefined behaviour. It could as well have crashed. doing back[i] on a zero sized string doesn't make sense.

First allocate memory for your string using resize.

```
back.resize(len);
```

before your `for` loop. Then your program makes sense.

Inserting a space before putting the actual character also makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr builtin function. no need  of for loop.

```
string my_copy_from(string in,short start,short len)
     {
    string back ;
    short i;

  /*  for (i=0 ; i<len; i++)
    {
      back[i]=' ';
      back[i]=in[start+i];


    }*/
    back = in.substr(start,len);

    return back;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the *back* now is **empty** if you don't assign any string-value neither reserve some space explicitly, and that means each access to *back* via operator[] is illegal. Despite no boundary-check performed, *access via operator[] beyond the index scope results in undefined behavior*, and it is lucky your compiler just ignore it.

To solve this problem, you can explicitly reserver some space for *back*

```
string s;
s.reserve(len); // or s.resize(len);
```

or use function *append*

```
string s;
s.append(in, start, len);
```

Actually, there already is a function named substr in string doing the same thing.

```
string s = in.substr(start, len);
```